# Unable to get authenticated using Redmine REST API

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, authentication, redmine

I am building a mobile application for Redmine. So, to get data from the Redmine server, I need to authenticate the user by passing his password and username. In Redmine API documentation, two methods are mentioned for authentication.

- using your regular login/password via HTTP Basic authentication.
- using your API key which is a handy way to avoid putting a password
  in a script. The API key may be attached to each request in one of
  the following way:
      - passed in as a "key" parameter
      - passed in as a username with a random password via HTTP Basic
  authentication
      - passed in as a "X-Redmine-API-Key" HTTP header (added in Redmine
  1.1.0)

I tried to send a get request as follows, I can see the issue list in response to the Get request in browser. But the success callback is not triggering.

```
var url= "http://username:password@redmine.qburst.com/issues.json";
$http({
    method: 'JSONP', 
    url: url
}).
success(function(data, status) {
    console.log(data);
}).
error(function(data, status) {
    console.log("Error "+status);
});
```

The following error is coming in console.

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

{"issues":[{"id":139989,"project":{"id":215,"name":"Book Meeting Room
```

Error status is `0`.

Comment: What do you have in Redmine logs? Find a peace of log with your request and post it.

Comment: @gotva I'm getting a new error now. I will modify the code now.

Comment: @govta I'm doing the coding in AngularJS now.

Comment: it is difficult to say where the problem is... I think you should (of course if it possible) to start your Redmine in Development mode (it will be much easier to debug the App) and find out where the exception raises. If there is a stack - post it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Different to standard JSON, [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) responses should be wrapped in a function call.

Instead of:

```
{"issues":[{"id":139989,"project":{"id":215,"name":"Book Meeting Room...
```

You should be getting something like the following from the server:

```
handler({"issues":[{"id":139989,"project":{"id":215,"name":"Book Meeting Room"}}]});
```

I ran into a similar issue and found that passing the `callback` or `jsonp` parameter with a handler name solved it. More info [here](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api#JSONP-Support) in the redmine documentation.

In jQuery this would be my request:

```
$.get('someurl', {'callback': 'foo'}, function (data, status, xhr) {
  ... request logic ...
  }, 'jsonp'
);
```

...and this would be your request with the callback parameter:

```
$http({
    method: 'JSONP', 
    url: url,
    callback: 'something'
}).
success(function(data, status) {
    console.log(data);
}).
error(function(data, status) {
    console.log("Error "+status);
});
```

This may not help you with the authentication woes but will hopefully get you past this error.